# How to select whole week on date picker angular material?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, datepicker, calendar

I want to select whole week on date picker with highligted on calander and want to choose first date of a week as values.
Eg if I select thursday select or highlight whole week from monday to sunday and restrict to overlap dates .
[here is sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOAvb.png)

Answer (score 0):

See the stackblitz link with the answer to your question.

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lsze1g?file=src/app/date-range-picker-selection-strategy-example.ts)